# HTML 5 based file upload plugin for multiple file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, file-upload

Anyone has a good suggestion which 'html 5 based plug ins' is best for multiple file upload in Ruby on Rails app? there are many, But I just want the simple file upload, preview, remove and add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and there are instructions for Rails.

but there's also [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which seems quite good.

Comment: Thanks Stevo. I just shortlisted blueimp, but it is worth trying plupload also. I will try both then.